# Changing values in Realtime Database Android Studio Java

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

so basically my problem is kind of weird. It updates the values however, I need to close the app again in order for me to update the fields again.
Here is my update code.

```
saveEditProfile_studentbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                String studentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(studentUser);
                Toast.makeText(StudentProfileEditAct.this, studentUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String replaceName = studentChangeFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                        String replacePhoneNumber = studentChangePhoneNum.getText().toString().trim();
                        Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
                        updates.put("fullName", replaceName);
                        updates.put("phoneNumber", replacePhoneNumber);

                        databaseReference.updateChildren(updates);
                        Toast.makeText(StudentProfileEditAct.this, "Changes has been made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

and here's my realtime database. I just want to change the name and the phone number.
But for some strange reason, it logout the current user and relog it back and when i'll try to update the values, the values from the realtime (fullname,phonenumber) the data goes back from the old value and new value and it's highlighted as yellow.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdn4S.png]

[image]
[image]

The images below when I tried to update the second time around without closing the app first.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a value in the database based on its current value, you should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to prevent conflicting writes.

But in your code, I see no reason to first read the user node before updating it. You can use this much simpler code, which may solve your problem:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String studentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(studentUser);
    String replaceName = studentChangeFullName.getText().toString().trim();
    String replacePhoneNumber = studentChangePhoneNum.getText().toString().trim();
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
    updates.put("fullName", replaceName);
    updates.put("phoneNumber", replacePhoneNumber);

    databaseReference.updateChildren(updates);
    Toast.makeText(StudentProfileEditAct.this, "Changes has been made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is to use the .setValue property in the Database Reference.

You may use a model class if you intended to change different fields at once.

Based on firebase documentation, valueeventlisteners are generally made for reading and listening to data changes and not writing which might be the problem of your code